# Android Fatal Exception occurring only on tablet

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a project that works fine in the emulator in Eclipse, but not on my actual Nexus 7. It's supposed to be a basic Phone book app, but so far it just displays names that it saves in a text file. When I run it on my Nexus, and tap the "add" button, it crashes. It apparently saves the data though, since if I open it again, the data is all there. I've tried searching for similar problems, but I haven't been able to find any. Here's the Logcat:

```
05-10 08:58:08.502: D/dalvikvm(16460): Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-10 08:58:08.532: D/dalvikvm(16460): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-10 08:58:08.682: D/libEGL(16460): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
05-10 08:58:08.702: D/libEGL(16460): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
05-10 08:58:08.722: D/libEGL(16460): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
05-10 08:58:08.752: D/OpenGLRenderer(16460): Enabling debug mode 0
05-10 08:58:26.612: D/dalvikvm(16460): GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 5% free 7454K/7812K, paused 10ms+2ms, total 45ms
05-10 08:58:33.752: D/AndroidRuntime(16460): Shutting down VM
05-10 08:58:33.752: W/dalvikvm(16460): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d44930)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at edu.mansfield.wardba21.phonebook.MainActivity$StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(MainActivity.java:162)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2180)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-10 08:58:33.762: E/AndroidRuntime(16460):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From that, I think it looks like something to do with the layout, but I don't have any idea how to fix it. Here's the .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the java:

```
package edu.mansfield.wardba21.phonebook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button delBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        final EditText nameEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText numbEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        final File nameFile = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "names.txt");
        final File numbFile = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "numbers.txt");
        if(!nameFile.exists())
        {
            try {
                nameFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(!numbFile.exists())
        {
            try {
                numbFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(nameFile);
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                names.add(sc.nextLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) { System.out.println("Failed to load file"); }

        try
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(numbFile);
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                numbers.add(sc.nextLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) { System.out.println("Failed to load file"); }

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name, number;
                name = nameEdit.getText().toString();
                number = numbEdit.getText().toString();

                if(!name.equals("") && !number.equals(""))
                {
                    names.add(name);
                    numbers.add(number);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream nameOut = new FileOutputStream(nameFile, true);
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(nameOut);
                        osw.write(name + "\n");
                        osw.flush();
                        osw.close();

                        FileOutputStream numbOut = new FileOutputStream(numbFile, true);
                        OutputStreamWriter osw2 = new OutputStreamWriter(numbOut);
                        osw2.write(number + "\n");
                        osw2.flush();
                        osw2.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   

                }
            }

        });

        delBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u can debug and check exactly on wht line the app is throwing NullPointerException in addBtn onClick..

Answer (score 1):

"names" is being used to back your underlying ArrayAdapter dataset - when you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() you are telling your adapter that its underlying data store has changed in someway and it should try to rebuild the list.

Unfortunately, your getItemId(position) method of StableArrayAdapter is backed by a HashMap that you only update when first constructing your adapter.

So if you add something to names, but the map doesn't get updated to reflect that... you will have NullPointerExceptions because the map doesn't have a corresponding object for:

```
return mIdMap.get(item);
```